# Set Flatpickr defaultDate through programmaticaly

Tags: jquery, flatpickr

I use Flatpickr from Wix Code thru an html-component. The communication, using postMessage/onMessage works perfectly. I can send a selected date from datepicker (html-component) back to Wix. Also, I can send to the component, from Wix. The problem is that I postMessage a valid date, it arrives perfectly, but then I need to set it as a flatpickr defaultDate property. And that, I cannot work out.
The line

```
$("#startDate").flatpickr.defaultDate = event.data;
```

or

```
$("#startDate").defaultDate = event.data;
```

does not set the defaultDate. `event.data` holds a valid date to set.

It´s a syntax problem, I know, but I cannot figure it out.

Code below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/themes/material_green.css"> 
  </head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data) {
        $("#startDate").flatpickr.defaultDate = event.data;
    }
};

function sendLoadMessage () {
    window.parent.postMessage("LoadOk", "*");
}
</script>
<body onload="sendLoadMessage ();" style="font-family: verdana;background-color:white;margin:0;padding:0">
  <div>
    <input type="text" hidden="true" id="startDate" data-input>
</div>
  
    <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--  Flatpickr  -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.2.3/flatpickr.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flatpickr/dist/l10n/es.js"></script>
<script>
$("#startDate").flatpickr({
    enableTime: false,
    dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
    inline: true,
    locale: "es",  
<!-- defaultDate : "01/05/2018",-->
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        window.parent.postMessage(selectedDates, "*");
    },
});


</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to first save your flatpickr instance on creation

```
var flatpickr = $("#startDate").flatpickr({});
```

and then you have to use the config setter

```
flatpickr.set('defaultDate', event.data);
```